# How can i send callback from socket.io server to client

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have server with socket.io and express

I listen incoming message

```
 let server = https.createServer(ssl, app);

    const io = new Server(server,{
        transports:'websocket',
        allowEIO3:true
    });

    io.on('connection', (socket) => {
        socket.onAny(async (eventName, type, data, ...args) => {
            switch (type) {
                case 'address':
                    break
                case 'hash':
                    rpc.getblockhash(1000).then(data => {
                        console.log('hash---', data)
                    });
                    break
                default:
                    break
            }
```

I getting request from client and get information

How can i send response ?

In example for socket.io i see this code

```
socket.emit(eventName[, …args][, ack])
eventName (String)
args
ack (Function)
Returns true
```

But i don't know eventName

Comment: What do you mean you don't know `eventName`? The `eventName` requires clients and server negotiations. Did you read the doc https://socket.io/docs/v4/emitting-events/?

Comment: Thanks. Do they have to be the same ?